# React: Why sibling components are re-rendered when setValue of hooks is called and how can I stop this. Please the code below

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

```
//Example Component
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import IndependentComponent from './independent-component'

function Example() {
    const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
                Click me
      </button>
            <IndependentComponent />
        </div>
    );
}


//Independent Component
import React from 'react'

const IndependentComponent = function () {
    console.log('This component is rendered when setCount is called in Example component')
    return (
        <div>Independent Sibling Component </div>
    )
}

export default IndependentComponent
```

Comment: `export default React.memo(IndependentComponent);`

Comment: actually `IndependentComponent ` is not a slibing component of  `Example`, but a child. a call to setCount will trigger a re-render to the Component and its children components, @Jayce444 's way will work

Comment: @Jayce444, Thanks. React.memo() works.

Comment: @Jerryc , yes the IndependentComponent is a child of Example, but I meant it to be the sibling of the button component, if I remove the setCount() from buttonclick handler, there are no re-renders of the IndependentComponent, but with setCount IndependentComponent is rendered everytime the button is clicked.

Comment: you are right, after removing the setCount from button click, IndependentComponent is not re-rendered, but its because the Example is not re-rendered. And with setCount  on click, Example actually re-rendered, lead to its children being re-rendered

Comment: @Jerryc, yes, now it made sense to me . Thanks for your comment (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a parent component is re-rendered, so are all its children. Thus even though `IndependentComponent` does not change with changes in parent component, it will still forcibly go through the render cycle.

There are 2 ways to prevent this, depending on whether it is a class based component or functional component.

1. For class based components, you could either extend the [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) class to never go through re-render cycle, or you could use [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) for more fine tuned control of when the component should re-render.
2. In the functional components case, which you are looking for, you can use [React.memo](https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-166-reactmemo-for-functional-components-rendering-control) HOC to make it behave like `PureComponent`, with the optional callback function to also have the fine-tuned control of `shouldComponentUpdate`.

So, in your use case of functional component, all you need to do is export your independent component like:

```
export default React.memo(IndependentComponent);
```

Comment: thanks React.memo works, however when I remove the setCount from the click handler, there are no re-renders of IndependentComponent upon button click, I guess its the nature of Hooks.